Allow ssh and ftp access to AWS EC2 ubuntu
Previously, I accessed /home/ubuntu through port 22 only with the ssh server key, and now an external partner company has to access FTP and work on /home/ubuntu.
So I created ftpuser account and password, and ftpuser can access to /home/ubuntu with ftp port 21.
But ftpuser account can't read/write/execute files.
Is there a way to allow external companies to access/read/write/execute ftp without affecting the ssh access rights of the existing ubuntu account?

This is not a programming question.

I feel like the solution would be to create a group in linux and grant permissions to that group then add the ftpuser to that group.
Set the group ownership of /home/ubuntu and its subdirectories to a    group that both the Ubuntu account and the FTP user belong to, or    create a new group for this purpose.
sudo chgrp -R mygroup /home/ubuntu

Replace mygroup with the name of the group you want to use.
Give the group read, write, and execute permissions, and provide read and execute permissions to others:
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/ubuntu

Add the FTP user to the group:
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup ftpuser

This assumes you are fine with them modifying that folder and that you don't have critical infrastructure on this machine otherwise I would review it more carefully.
